# Memo и поиск в нем

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Как замутить поиск в Memo? Delphi6... Заранее благодарен!

Comment: К сам не додумался спасибо попробую там получаеться циклом for можно сделать и проверять постоянно то или не то, только вот, а если будет: Привет как  дела Любовь? ввожу допустим в Edit Любовь но он не че не найдет потому что будет проверять всю строку даже лишний пробел будет мешать такому поиску...

Comment: Искать в строке нужно через функцию `pos()`

Answer (score 1):

Штатной функции поиска у `TMemo` нет.

Но есть свойство `Lines` типа `TStrings` в котором хранится весь текст. Если простыми словами, то это массив строк. Функции поиска вхождений у `TStrings` тоже нет. Но, можно воспользоваться обычным перебором. `Lines.Count` - кол-во строк. `Lines[0]` - строка с индексом 0.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант (pattern - то, что ищем)

```
var
    position: Integer;
begin
    position := pos(pattern, MemoX.Text);
    if (position > 0) then
        begin
            MemoX.SelStart := position;
            MemoX.SelLength := Length(pattern);
            MemoX.SetFocus;
        end;
end;
```